# Move /var/www outside of root (to different partition)

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I did a search on stackoverflow/superuser, but couldn't quite find what I need. I used a script to setup my linux server. My www folder (/var/www/) is located on the root partition, and the capacity of this partition is limited. Can I move the www folder so I can run my website on a different partition? I would like www to be running from the /home/ folder, which is on the 1.9TB partition.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move it:

```
mv /var/www /home/USERNAME/www
```

Then, create a symbolic link so you don't have to change any config:

```
ln -s /home/USERNAME/www /var/www
```

Comment: you also need correct permissions on the partition aka not 777

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered many times.
You need to change the DocumentRoot setting in your httpd.conf
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server

Comment: Is not same thing when you use another partition. I have done several times and tested, there's something more to do when documentRoot is in another partition.